# Send cookie with ffmpeg input

Tags: ffmpeg

I currently have a cookie.txt file that looks like this.

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1547252593  GPS 1
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1552434792  PREF    f1=50000000&hl=en
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   1562802793  VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE  inJgRBNv-3I
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   0   YSC 9U9ILYfJDyA
.youtube.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   0   s_gl    1d69aac621b2f9c0a25dade722d6e24bcwIAAABVUw==
```

In [ffmpeg's documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#HTTP-Cookies) it shows that you can send a cookie via a command like so

```
ffplay -cookies "nlqptid=nltid=tsn; path=/; domain=somedomain.com;" http://somedomain.com/somestream.m3u8
```

How would I send this cookie.txt file as the input given this, would I convert each line of the cookie.txt file including the comments and space between line breaks? Would I send it as one long string? Neither? All help is appreciated.